# Is a monoid finitely generated by finite order elements periodic?

Tags: group-theory, monoid

This may be a simple question, but I can't make it out right now.

> Let $M$ be a monoid, and $g_1, \ldots, g_n \in M$ be elements of finite order in $M$.  Is $\langle g_1, \ldots, g_n \rangle$ periodic (i.e, have all its elements of finite order)?

The monoid I'm  interested in is the multiplicative monoid of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{N}$.

Thanks.

Comment: It's true for the $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{N}$ for silly reasons: the only elements of finite order are $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1& 0 \\ 0 &1\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Damn, you're right!  That makes me realize that ... this is not the question I wanted to ask!  Wow, never post late on the 31st of December.  I'll launch a new question with the correct wording.

Comment: The new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16038/is-a-monoid-finitely-generated-by-periodic-matrices-periodic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Edit because I misread the question somewhat.)

To show that this is false for an arbitrary monoid it suffices to exhibit a monoid generated by elements of finite order which has elements of infinite order.  Take, for example, $M = \langle a, b | a^2 = b^2 = 1 \rangle$.  In this monoid $ab$ has infinite order.  One can see this geometrically by constructing the following linear representation: let $a$ and $b$ act by reflection across two lines through the origin at an angle $\theta$ with respect to each other which is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.  (For this reason $M$ is known as the infinite dihedral group.)

Probably the most important example of this phenomenon "in nature" is the [modular group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group), which has group presentation $\langle a, b | a^2 = b^3 = 1 \rangle$ and hence is generated by an element of order $2$ and an element of order $3$.

I am not sure about your particular $M$.  Does $\mathbb{N}$ contain $0$ for you?  (If not I am having trouble finding *any* nontrivial elements of finite order.)

Comment: @Qiaochu: I don't think the OP is wondering if the monoid of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{N}$ has elements of infinite order, but whether a submonoid generated by element of finite order may contain any. So I'm not sure your first paragraph is appropriate. Of course, the result is false in general, with your first $M$ being the infinite dihedral group.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: @Qiaochu: It must contain $0$, otherwise there is no identity (hence no monoid)...

Comment: @Arturo: I think the only elements of finite order are permutations.  Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: @Qiaochu: It is the case in $n=2$, and it seemed that way for $n=3$ as well (though I didn't check it thoroughly). It would not surprise me.

Comment: Right, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ for me.  Thank you for your answers, guys.

Answer (score 4):

For the case you're interested in it is true, because the set of finite order $n$-by-$n$ matrices over $\mathbb{N}$ is precisely the set of permutation matrices.  In fact, every invertible element of $M_n(\mathbb{N})$ is a permutation matrix.  (Here $\mathbb{N}$ contains $0$, and invertible means invertible in the monoid $M_n(\mathbb{N})$ with multiplication.)

Suppose that $B=(b_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{N})$ is not a permutation matrix.  Then either one of the entries of $B$ is greater than $1$, one of the rows or columns of $B$ has more than one nonzero entry, or one of the rows or columns of $B$ is zero.   Let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{N})$ be invertible.

Suppose first that $B$ has an entry greater than $1$, i.e., $b_{i_0j_0}\gt1$ for some $i_0$ and $j_0$.  Since $A$ is invertible, its $i_0^\text{th}$ column is not zero, so there is an $i_1$ such that $a_{i_1i_0}\gt0$.  Then if $AB=(c_{ij})$, we have $c_{i_1j_0}\geq a_{i_1i_0}b_{i_0j_0}\gt1$, so that $AB\neq I$.  Hence, $B$ is not invertible in this case.

Now suppose that $B$ has a row with more than one nonzero entry, i.e., $b_{i_0j_0}\gt0$ and $b_{i_0j_1}\gt0$ for some $i_0$ and $j_0\neq j_1$.  Again, there is an $i_1$ such that $a_{i_1i_0}\gt0$, and we have $c_{i_1j_0}\geq a_{i_1i_0}b_{i_0j_0}\gt0$ and $c_{i_1j_1}\geq a_{i_1i_0}b_{i_0j_1}\gt0$, so again $AB\neq I$.  A similar argument applies if $B$ has a column with more than one nonzero entry, either by multiplying in the other order, or by considering the transpose.  Thus in either case $B$ is not invertible.

This leaves only the case that $B$ has a zero row or column, in which case it is even a zero divisor.  Thus in any case, $B$ is not invertible.